# A probability question over multiple questions test.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I was wondering about this problem: say I have to take a test made of $31$ questions chosen among a database of $140$ questions total.
Those questions are open questions (that is, not multiple choice questions).

Say that I know all the database of questions, because it's public, but I have studied poorly and I only know $100$ of the $140$ questions.

Is there a way to find a sort of "average" probability for which al least $25$ of the $31$ questions are among the $100$ I know? I said $25$ but we could do $n$ to generalise.

I was thinking that something I should (?) take into account is the number of ways the professor can choose $31$ questions among the $140$ that is

$$\binom{140}{31} = 11338699879051838313792998934400$$

Now from here I don't know how to proceed. I maybe think that I should take into account the fact that I know $100/140$ of the questions, but I don't know how to put the $40$ questions I don't know into account, in the total ways to choose the questions.

Also my "at least" makes the problem harder...

Comment: Not much harder, because the numbers are small.  Just sum over the cases (exactly $25$, exactly $26$, and so on).  Of course, you are implicitly assuming that the $31$ test questions are chosen randomly (so that any group of $31$ is equally likely to be chosen) though you did not state this.

Comment: @lulu Yes, they are chosen randomly. So what I should do is a sum like

$$\frac{25}{31}\cdot \frac{1}{ \binom{140}{31}} + \frac{26}{31}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{140}{31} }+ \ldots$$

?

Comment: I don't understand.  The number of ways to choose $31$ from $140$ such that *exactly* $n$ of them are from the $100$ special ones is $\binom {100}n\times \binom {40}{31-n}$.  I don't understand your fractional terms.

Comment: @lulu Ah blimey! I did not see that o.o

Answer (score 2):

This is a hypergeometric probability.  In the question pool, there are $100$ questions you have prepared for, and $40$ questions you have not.  If $31$ questions are selected without replacement and $X$ is the random number of prepared questions on the test, then the desired probability is

$$\Pr[X \ge 25] = \sum_{x=25}^{31} \frac{\binom{100}{x} \binom{40}{31-x}}{\binom{140}{31}}.$$

Comment: Oh, never heard of hypergeometric... I shall study more then! I will start studying your answer. Thank you!!